# Dimension of a representation and the order of an element in a group

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Let $V$ be a representation of a finite group $G$ with $V$ being finite dimensional. Fix a $g \in G$. Is it necessarily true that $\dim V \geq \operatorname{ord} g$?

Comment: What about the trivial representation?

Comment: Right, but what if we assume that $V$ is not the trivial representation?

Comment: $V$ could be the direct sum of 2 trivial representations, and $g$ could have order 3.  Even if you insist that $V$ is irreducible, there are many groups that have irreducible representations of dimension 2, for example, all the dihedral groups, which can have elements of arbitrarily large order.

Comment: Still not true. $S_n$ has a non-trivial representation on spaces of dimension $2$ (induced by the quotient map $S_n\to C_2$, and letting the nontrivial element of $C_2$ act by exchanging coordinates). Even if the representation is faithful: $S_n$ acts on an $n$-dimensional space by acting on the coordinates, but for $n\gt 5$, contains elements of order larger than $n$ (e.g., $S_5$ has elements of order $6$).

Comment: If $G$ is abelian then all its irreducible representations have dimension 1, but (unless it's the one-element group) it has elements of order greater than 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not at all.  Let $V$ be a one-dimensional vector space, and let $G$ be the two-element cyclic group, where the generator for $G$ acts as multiplication by $-1$.  Then $V$ is one-dimensional, but $G$ has an element of order two.